# Creating "duplicate" rows with one variable in R

Tags: r

Had a hard time naming this question, as I'm not sure what to call this maneuver. However, the idea is fairly simple. I have a dataframe in which some of the values are vectors.

```
letters <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

numbers <- list(34, 23, c(23, 34, 45), 23, c(45,56,43,12))

df <- data.frame(letters)
df$numbers <- numbers

df

    letters numbers
1   a   34
2   b   23
3   c   c(23, 34, 45)
4   d   23
5   e   c(45, 56, 43, 12)
```

What I want to obtain is a data.frame that duplicates all rows that contain vectors in the column numbers by the number of objects in those vectors. They must be exact duplicates except for the numbers column, which should be variable. Like so:

```
    letters numbers
1   a   34
2   b   23
3   c   23
4   c   24
5   c   45
6   d   23
7   e   55
8   e   56
9   e   43
10  e   12
```

Any easy solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `unnest`

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(df, numbers)
#   letters numbers
#    (fctr)   (dbl)
#1        a      34
#2        b      23
#3        c      23
#4        c      34
#5        c      45
#6        d      23
#7        e      45
#8        e      56
#9        e      43
#10       e      12
```

Comment: Beautiful. Just what i was looking for. Very neat.

Answer (score 2):

The **tidyr** option is the neatest, but if you want to use base R, you can do:

```
stack(setNames(numbers, letters))

#    values ind
# 1      34   a
# 2      23   b
# 3      23   c
# 4      34   c
# 5      45   c
# 6      23   d
# 7      45   e
# 8      56   e
# 9      43   e
# 10     12   e
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion as well!